# Compare 2 column values and insert value from 3rd to 4th

Tags: excel-formula

I reviewed the other post similar to this, but I can't get the formula to work.

In this example, I need to compare values in column I to values in column O, and if they match, insert value from column P into column K.

Thanks in advance!

```
    I                 K            O             P
1  SKU             Quantity      SKU 2        Quantity
2  00866149                      31819        21 
3  00866246                      00866149     24
4  009016018771                  00866246     27
5  009016018788                  01140606      6
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the formula:

```
=INDEX(P:P,MATCH(I:I,O:O,0))
```

you can read more on it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214142)